# After skiping the test, still jest takes long time, how to make it to 0 time

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I am doing testing with jest.js in my angular project. It seems that, my whole testing process take closly 45min, which i not requried. I decided to skip some of unwanted tests from the project. for that I am skipping it out.

But still I am getting `25.36s` for the skipped file. how to make it to `0s` instead? here is my test case: (`xdescribe`) i skipped.

```
import { TestBed, inject, getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { IboSharedLibModule } from '@ibo/ibo-shared-lib';
import { CourseMappingAddGuard } from './course-mapping-add.guard';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { provideMockStore, MockStore } from '@ngrx/store/testing';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import * as subscribe from '../previous-course-linkage/state/selectors/course-mapping.selector';

xdescribe('CourseMappingAddGuard', () => {
  let injector: TestBed;
  let guard: CourseMappingAddGuard;
  function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
    const store: MockStore<any> = null;
  }
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [],
      imports: [
        StoreModule.forRoot({}, { runtimeChecks: { strictStateImmutability: true, strictActionImmutability: true } }),
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        IboSharedLibModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
            deps: [HttpClient],
          },
          isolate: true,
        }),
      ],
      providers: [
        CourseMappingAddGuard,
        provideMockStore({
          selectors: [],
        }),
      ],
    });
    injector = getTestBed();
    guard = injector.get(CourseMappingAddGuard);
  });

  it('should redirect to parent page if no data available', () => {
    expect(guard.canActivate()).toEqual(false);
  });
});
```

here is the test result:

```
$ jest course-mapping-add.guard.spec.ts
Test Suites: 1 skipped, 0 of 1 total
Tests:       1 skipped, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        16.232s, estimated 20s
Ran all test suites matching /course-mapping-add.guard.spec.ts/i.
Done in 25.36s.
```

any one please help me to understand? thanks in advance.

Comment: I get the same issue. Took me an hour of debugging! lol. I have some async tests that query remote api and marking them with `xtest` still make the whole suite take longer than if I physically remove the code. I wonder if it actually queries the server, this could be a severe issue.